# How to remove "leading" zeros from version number string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I remove the "leading" zeros from following version number string?

5.002.008.80911 --> 5.2.8.80911

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.split` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
s = "5.002.008.80911"
print(".".join(str(int(i)) for i in s.split(".")))
```

**Output:**

```
5.2.8.80911
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a utility function in [`packaging`](https://github.com/pypa/packaging):

```
>>> from packaging.utils import canonicalize_version
>>> canonicalize_version('5.002.008.80911')
'5.2.8.80911'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with a negative lookbehind regex pattern:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\d)0+', '', '5.002.008.80911')
```

This returns:

```
'5.2.8.80911'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
res = ".".join([str(int(i)) for i in inputVerNo.split(".")])

return res
```

Basically split by Dot and convert string to integers to remove zeroes and then back to string.